# error 42601 syntax near postgresql

Tags: c#, .net, postgresql, entity-framework, entity

i was trying to save data with Entity framework and database postgresql

```
private OctopusDBEntities _dbContext;

public PendaftaranSiswaDA()
    {
        _dbContext = new OctopusDBEntities();
    }

    public resultVM SubmitFirstReg(resultVM model)
    {
        siswa_first_reg _tab_first_reg = new siswa_first_reg();

        try
        {
            Mapper.CreateMap<FirstRegVM, siswa_first_reg>().ForAllMembers(cond => cond.Condition(src => !src.IsSourceValueNull));
            _tab_first_reg = Mapper.Map(model.firstRegVM, _tab_first_reg);
            _dbContext.Entry(_tab_first_reg).State = EntityState.Added;
            _dbContext.SaveChanges(); // --- i have an error from here
            model.isRegister = true;
            model.message = "Data sudah terdaftar!";
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            throw e;
        }
        return model;
    }
```

the error said syntax error at or near "(", like as on the pict [image]

this is the query that was generated by entityframework.

```
INSERT INTO (SELECT siswa_first_reg.reg_no_registration, siswa_first_reg.reg_full_name, siswa_first_reg.reg_last_school_name, siswa_first_reg.reg_age, siswa_first_reg.reg_mobile_no, siswa_first_reg.reg_birth_place, siswa_first_reg.reg_birth_date, siswa_first_reg.reg_address, siswa_first_reg.reg_email, siswa_first_reg.reg_status, siswa_first_reg.reg_registration_date, siswa_first_reg.reg_gender FROM octo_test.siswa_first_reg AS siswa_first_reg) reg_no_registration, reg_full_name, reg_last_school_name, reg_age, reg_mobile_no, reg_birth_place, reg_birth_date, reg_address, reg_email, reg_status, reg_registration_date, reg_gender) VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6, $7, $8, NULL, NULL, NULL, $9)
```

why the query was generated like that?
and how should i do to fix it?

Thank you so much.

Comment: Please don’t post errors etc as images. Copy the text from there, including the generated query in its entirety so we can see what it actually is. Now only part of it is visible

Comment: `INSERT INTO (` looks like you are missing a table name there.

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen sorry before,, i was edited it, but i think it's little bit different from the pict. I mean on the pict it was like \nsiswa_first_reg.reg_no_registration, but when i open it, just siswa_first_reg.reg_no_registration

Comment: @mjwills yeah,, that's my question, why there's no table name in it. Because, the query was generated by entity framework. I mean, is there something wrong with my entity framework that cause wrong query?

Answer (score 1):

I don't have an answer for the OP, but the question did make me realise my own mistake. Despite the exception often being quite unhelpful if it does not actually include the raw query, the chances are it's a query format/syntax issue. For example, I had recently changed a query plus some other things in my C# code, however, I had missed a comma in a parameter list!

Comment: This exact thing just happened to me, too! Racking my brain ffor an hour until I came across this question and your reply. :)

Answer (score -3):

Sorry for lack of information.
As i tried to solve this, i found an answer.

Just, wanna share, maybe some people has same case.
The codes above has nothing wrong.
The problem is on the database.
I don't set the primary key on my table.

Thank you, for any attention and support.